# MySql Huge data operations (over 30 million datarecords) - most optimal way

Tags: mysql, database, performance

Table one: **35 million records**
Table two: **1,6 million records**

I'm executing an update query in table one based upon 3 equalities. Both tables are pure data colls without any keys.

```
`UPDATE table1,table2
SET table1.TravelTime=table2.CongestionTime
WHERE table1.From = table2.From
AND table1.To = table2.To
AND table1.Time= table2.Time`
```

Yet this operation seems to be doomed to be slow. Is there a way to be creative to speed up this process?

Currently a query is running at a mere 300 updates/second suggesting it would take 33 hours to complete this query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Both tables are pure data colls without any keys.

I think you just said it there. You need indexes to get good performance when working with this amount of data.

Try adding multi-column indexes:

- `(From, To, Time)` for Table1.
- `(From, To, Time, CongestionTime)` for Table2.

You may also want to consider if it is appropriate to add a foreign key constraint.

**Related documentation**

- [CREATE INDEX Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-index.html)

Comment: Agreed, the way to speed this up would be for all the data to be in the index and query not to have to touch the tables for the join. I think CongestionTime should be in the index for table 2 though.

Comment: @PreetSangha: Good point. Then it forms a covering index. I'll update.

Comment: Hence in practise I need to update my tables or do I just need to update my query with a create index statement ?

Comment: Update your table and create the index there!

Comment: Thank you Tobiask. I assume that now I can compare the keys to update the data. Thanks guys.

Comment: @GijsHompes. I would if possible, create the indexes on a seperate disk if possible as this will give much better performance.

Comment: Ok I created indexes in both tables. I tried editing my query to `...WHERE key1 = key2;` Yet mySQL trows an error stating that the "col" don't exist. Can I use my 'left' cols as 'index' reference?

Comment: @GijsHompes: You don't need to change the query. Just add the indexes.

Comment: @MarkByers, thx ! Reduced my 33 hour query to one of 10 minutes :)